# Solarwinds Netflow Generator is crashing with file not found

Tags: windows, netflow

I am using [this tool from Solar Winds](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/free-tools-trials/f/flow-tools-bundle/1238/solarwinds-flow-tools-bundle-quick-reference-guide) to generate v9 Netflow events.

It was working until an OS update a few days ago. Now, it starts, but when I generate events it crashes every time. I have tried running it as Administrator and my regular privileged user. The cause might be a .NET update.

I have also tried using the processmonitoring tools, but I am not seeing an obvious root cause. Though I am pretty inexperienced using those tools.

Windows events viewer shows this exception:

```
Application: NetFlowGenerator.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at SolarWinds.NetFlowGenerator.WPFGui.Content.GeneratorSettings.CreateGeneratorSettings(SolarWinds.NetFlowGenerator.WPFGui.Content.Data.Configuration)
   at SolarWinds.NetFlowGenerator.WPFGui.Content.Data.Tab.<OnRun>b__39_0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: you pay for the support of SolarWinds and dont open a support ticket for this? WHy?

Comment: I don't pay for support. It's a free tool. It clearly says it's a free tool in the URL.

Comment: Your sentence feels offensive. Don't do this. Remember we will not know that you don't pay for the support. We don't know you or your infrastructure. We have to get as most as possible information from any questions to supply the best possible solution

Comment: It is the only thing I am using from Solar Winds. I am trying to send v9 templates to a third party product to test if that third party product can parse the v9 templates correct. It was working before the OS update. I am just looking for suggesting on how to troubleshoot a Window application. Like how to see what file it's not finding, which I have not been able to figure out.